# Poor performance of TEXT column Index in sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, indexing

I have a simple table for key/value storage:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Cache (
            id INTEGER NOT NULL,
            key TEXT NOT NULL,
            value BLOB DEFAULT NULL,
            UNIQUE (key),
            PRIMARY KEY (id) )
```

Now, with 350k records, I want to get about 60k records by `key` which sometimes takes around 10 minutes!

```
    for chunk in chunks:
        param_subs = ','.join(itertools.repeat('?', len(chunk)))
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM `Cache` WHERE `key` in ({param_subs})", chunk)
        data.extend(cursor.fetchall())
```

I don't know what else I can do about it?

**PS**: The key column is actually sha1 hash of some strings, if it helps to find a way to speed things up.

List of indexes:

```
[(0, 'sqlite_autoindex_Cache_1', 1, 'u', 0)]
```

and my query and it's plan are:

```
'EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM `CACHE` WHERE `KEY` IN ("FOO", "BAR")'

[(0, 0, 0, 'SEARCH TABLE CACHE USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_Cache_1 (key=?)'),
(0, 0, 0, 'EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 1')]
```

Comment: Try indexing this column

Comment: @GProst I already marked it as unique and I thought it creates an index under the hood, doesn't it?

Comment: Not necessary, there is a unique constraint and unique index, check by querying `PRAGMA index_list('table_name');`

Comment: @GProst it shows "[(0, 'sqlite_autoindex_Cache_1', 1, 'u', 0)]" and when I look at query plan, it uses this index.

Comment: So you're supplying 60k hashes into a query?

Comment: @GProst not at once, I batch them into 1k long batches.

Comment: Is there a way for you to query these records based on some other grouping parameter? What does unity these records? Why do you have to query so many records by key?

Comment: @GProst I'm using sqlite as a key value store.